# Why are strings and arrays treated differently when using copy()?

Tags: python

I am wondering why, in the following snippet, the attributes in the copied object `b` behave differently. `b.lst` yields the updated values of `a.lst`, but `b.str` remains with the original value assigned to `a.str`. Why is this?

```
>>> import copy
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.str = "Hola"
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a.lst.append(4)
>>> a.str = "Adios"
>>> print b.lst
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print b.str
Hola
```

Comment: Please don't refer to lists as arrays. There are several array types in core Python: tuple, list, bytearray, and array.array, and the very popular Numpy library has arrays as well. Using the correct terminology reduces ambiguity, and makes it easier for people in the future doing searches.

Comment: The fundamental difference here isn't the difference between `str` and `list`, but the difference between the `=` operator (which rebinds the name) and the `.append` method (which simply mutates the object). If you did `a.lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]` then `b.lst` would be unaffected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: copy.**copy**(*x*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Return a **shallow copy** of *x*.

To really duplicate the list (or any mutable object), use `copy.deepcopy` instead.

> ```py
> >>> import copy
> >>>
> >>> class A(object): pass  # In Python 3, object is extended by default
> ...
> >>>
> >>> a = A()
> >>> a.lst = [1, 2, 3]
> >>> a.str = "Hola"
> >>>
> >>> b = copy.copy(a)
> >>>
> >>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
> >>>
> >>> a.lst.append(4)
> >>> a.str = "Adios"
> >>>
> >>> print(b.str, b.lst)
> Hola [1, 2, 3, 4]
> >>>
> >>> print(c.str, c.lst)
> Hola [1, 2, 3]
> ```